# correcta forma de guardar multiple datos usando ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Hola amigos tengo el siguiente inconveniente, necesito poder guardar los datos que me genera una tabla a travez de ajax

La tabla en cuestion me crea diversos tr por ejemplo:

```
<form>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Detalles</th><th>Monto</th>
</tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="desc[]" value="1"></td><td><input type="hidden" name="monto[]" value="1"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="desc[]" value="1"></td><td><input type="hidden" name="monto[]" value="1"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="desc[]" value="1"></td><td><input type="hidden" name="monto[]" value="1"></td></tr>
</table>
<button type="button" onclick="insertardatos()">Pagar Ahora</button>
</form>
```

uso el siguiente script para insertar los datos mediante ajax

```
function insertardatos() {
         var dataA="test";
         var dataB="100";
         var dataSend="desc="+dataA+"&monto="+dataB;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "insert.data.php",
            data: dataSend,
            success: function(){
               }
        });
    }
```

Como puedo introducir todos los datos, alguna guia , Gracias por anticipado

Comment: Tus variables `dataA` y `dataB` son valores estáticos, cuál es tu idea sobre eso?  Puedes utilizar el objeto `new formData` para obtener los valores mediante el atributo `name` de tus inputs, pero puedes investigar en internet poniendo el mismo título, seguro encuentras muchas formas de hacerlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te comparto esta solución.
En este codigo lo que realiza es que cuando envies el formulario, este no vaya a buscar cada uno de los inputs de este sino que los selecciona todos en un array el cual luego se envia en la petición mediante ajax.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(document).on('submit', '#miform', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var dataSend=$('#miform').serializeArray(); // obtengo los inputs y sus valores del formulario
      console.log('Datos del formulario', dataSend);
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "insert.data.php",
         dataType: 'json',
         data: dataSend,
         success: function(response){
          console.log(response);
         }
      });
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="miform">
<table>
<tr>
<th>Detalles</th><th>Monto</th>
</tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="desc[]" value="1"></td><td><input type="hidden" name="monto[]" value="1"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="desc[]" value="2"></td><td><input type="hidden" name="monto[]" value="2"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="desc[]" value="3"></td><td><input type="hidden" name="monto[]" value="3"></td></tr>
</table>
<button type="submit">Pagar Ahora</button>
</form>
```

Espero te sirva la solución.